# Drag from desktop/folder to GUI

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I searched for this online but couldn't find any answer related to my problem.

My idea is to  create a Python GUI with tkinter which could read text files from dragging from the desktop or a folder to the GUI itself, like for example on facebook (PC) you can drag images or text files to a chat and it processes it as a file.

Is there any way I could know what is my mouse dragging or clicking (outside the GUI) so I could save it on a variable? Or a library which has already that functionality?

Comment: There is no built in function to do that in tkinter. 
I think you have to write that by yourself.

Comment: @Module_art you know how could I start? Sorry but I'm kind of a newbie yet

Comment: Maybe start with this [Drag and drop support](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/tkinter.dnd.html). This isn't that what you want, the rest is up to you. good luck